# Is this the correct way to make a postrequest to login into a website

Tags: python-3.x, authentication, python-requests

Hi guys Id like to start with requests and just login into a website.

Somehow it doesnt work right or how can I post a status code

```
import requests

LOGIN = 'https://www.snipes.com/login'
payload = {
'username': 'username',
'password': 'password'
}

with requests.session() as s:
s.post(LOGIN, data=payload)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get status code as,

```
In [38]: import requests

In [39]: LOGIN = 'https://www.snipes.com/login'

In [40]: payload = {
    ...: 'username': 'username',
    ...: 'password': 'password'
    ...: }

In [41]: with requests.session() as s:
    ...:     res = s.post(LOGIN, data=payload)
    ...:

In [42]: res
Out[42]: <Response [410]>

In [43]: res.status_code
Out[43]: 410
```

Comment: So 410 is wrong I guess, something with my login form isnt working. Do you know what

Comment: Dont seem to work. Can I see in source code if they really use "username" for their login form?